# How to retrieve a React property from an event object

Tags: reactjs, properties, event-handling

How can a property set in a React component be easily retrieved from an event object?

**Minimal verifiable complete example**

Assume a `click` event on the following component. It is a header in a table; `onClick` calls a `sortRequest`, a function built to sort the collection by the clicked header. I need the `sort_key` to know which column to sort on:

```
<TableCell sort_key={sort_key} onClick={sortRequest}>{name}</TableCell>
```

In the event handler, I need to grab the `sort_key` from the event object, so that I can sort the collection based on the header that User clicked, but I can't find it buried in the event object properties!

```
const sortRequest = (e) => {
    // HERE: Where in e is the sort_key property?
}
```

Now I've resorted to string manipulations on `outerHTML`, like so:

```
const sortRequest = (e) => {
    let s = e.currentTarget.outerHTML
    let start = s.indexOf("sort_key") + 10
    let finish = s.indexOf("\"", start)
    sort_field = s.substring(start, finish)
}
```

...but this is rather cumbersome; I feel like there must be a better way. Tyvm Keith :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the **sort_key** as a parameter to the onClick event handler

```
<TableCell sort_key={sort_key} onClick={() => sortRequest(sort_key)}>{name}</TableCell>
```

```
const sortRequest = key => {
  console.log(key)
}
```